# Intersection of two strings in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, intersection

Need a Java function to find intersection of two strings. i.e. characters common to the strings.

Example:

```
String s1 = new String("Sychelless");
String s2 = new String("Sydney");
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using `HashSet<Character>`:

```
HashSet<Character> h1 = new HashSet<Character>(), h2 = new HashSet<Character>();
for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++)                                            
{
  h1.add(s1.charAt(i));
}
for(int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++)
{
  h2.add(s2.charAt(i));
}
h1.retainAll(h2);
Character[] res = h1.toArray(new Character[0]);
```

This is `O(m + n)`, which is asymptotically optimal.

Comment: what is O(m+n) and how do u arrive at that complexity and what do mean by asymptotically optimal

Comment: `m` and `n` are the lengths of the strings.  Adding, removing, and checking a HashSet item are all O(1).  So it's basically m (add) + n (add) + m (one check for every element in h1) + m (up to m removals) + m (converting to character array).  So that's 4m + n, which is O(m + n) (the constant drops out).  O is Big O.  Asymptotically optimal means that there is no algorithm with a smaller big O.

Comment: The "O(m + n)" stuff is used for analyzing the time and space requirements of algorithms. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: @MonaJalal, it's just required so that toArray returns an array of type Character.

This is a consequence of Java's somewhat incomplete generic system (it was added on later, so they couldn't do everything a new system like C# could).  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toArray%28T[]%29 .

Comment: This approach of set fails for following input "aa","aa" .

Answer (score 9):

Extract the characters

```
String.toCharArray
```

Put them in a Set
Find the intersection

```
Set.retainAll
```

Answer (score 7):

Most basic approach:

```
String wordA = "Sychelless";  
String wordB = "Sydney";  
String common = "";  

for(int i=0;i<wordA.length();i++){  
    for(int j=0;j<wordB.length();j++){  
        if(wordA.charAt(i)==wordB.charAt(j)){  
            common += wordA.charAt(i)+" ";  
            break;
        }  
    }  
}  
System.out.println("common is: "+common);
```

Comment: Output from this is `"common is: S y e e "`. I would not expect a correct solution to include duplicates (at least not if both words don't have the letters multiple times).

Comment: This is `O(m * n)` because of the nested loop.  Separately, you can easily make the String creation more efficient with a `StringBuilder`, since you know the upper bound of the size ahead of time.  Rasmus is also right that the intersection should be a set (no duplicates).

Comment: The duplication can be fixed very easy adding a condition one line before appending to the "common" String like: if(!common.contains(wordA.charAt(i)+""))

Answer (score 3):

More detail on saugata's response (appeared while I was writing this): -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "Seychelles";
    String s2 = "Sydney";
    Set<Character> ss1 = toSet(s1);
    ss1.retainAll(toSet(s2));
    System.out.println(ss1);
}

public static Set<Character> toSet(String s) {
    Set<Character> ss = new HashSet<Character>(s.length());
    for (char c : s.toCharArray())
        ss.add(Character.valueOf(c));
    return ss;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the algorithm you are looking for is the [problem of the longest common subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)

Comment: the solution is posted by above members

Answer (score 1):

Found same question here, refer this

[Implementing an efficent algorithm to find the intersection of two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090453/implement-an-algorithm-that-takes-two-strings-as-input-and-returns-the-intersect)

Comment: This is for c# though, but the algorithm is the same

Answer (score 1):

By means of Guava this task seems much easier:

```
String s1 = new String("Sychelless");
String s2 = new String("Sydney");
Set<String> setA = Sets.newHashSet(Splitter.fixedLength(1).split(s1));
Set<String> setB = Sets.newHashSet(Splitter.fixedLength(1).split(s2));
Sets.intersection(setA, setB);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Optimized solution**:

```
public static String twoStrings(String s1, String s2){

    HashSet<Character> stringOne =  new HashSet<Character>(), stringTwo = new HashSet<Character>();  
    int stringOneLength = s1.length();
    int stringTwoLength = s2.length();
    for(int i=0; i<stringOneLength || i<stringTwoLength; i++) {
        if(i < stringOneLength)
            stringOne.add(s1.charAt(i));
        if(i < stringTwoLength)
            stringTwo.add(s2.charAt(i));
    }
    stringOne.retainAll(stringTwo);

    return stringOne.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html). And [`retainAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-)  in `TreeSet` to get matched elements.

> Oracle Doc:
>
> ```
> retainAll(Collection<?> c)
> ```
>
> Retains only the elements in this set that are contained in the
>   specified collection (optional operation).

```
String s1 = new String("Sychelless");
String s2 = new String("Sydney");

Set<Character> firstSet = new TreeSet<Character>();
for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
    firstSet.add(s1.charAt(i));
}

Set<Character> anotherSet = new TreeSet<Character>();
for(int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) {
    anotherSet.add(s2.charAt(i));
}

firstSet.retainAll(anotherSet);
System.out.println("Matched characters are " + firstSet.toString());//print common strings

//output > Matched characters are [S, e, y]
```

Answer (score -5):

```
s1.contains(s2) returns true;
s1.indexOf(s2) returns 0. 
s1.indexOf("foo") returns -1
```

For more sophisticated cases use class Pattern.

Comment: how it will give common chars

Comment: It gives substring and I am 99% sure that it is what he needs.