# Finding uppercase characters in a user's string and counting them

Tags: java, regex

i wanted to get the uppercase characters in the string and also there count

```
package TEST;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class case_test {
    public static void main(String agrs[]) {

        String str1 = "", regx;
        regx = "[A-Z]+";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regx);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str1);
        int count = 0;

        System.out.println("ENTER A SENTENCE");
        str1 = sc.nextLine();

        while (matcher.find())
            System.out.println(str1.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end())
                    + "*");

        count++;
    }
}
```

I wanted to get the uppercase characters in the string and also their amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string intersection ([Intersection of two strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448370/intersection-of-two-strings-in-java)) using originalString & originalString.toUpperCase().

Answer (score 2):

You can try with:

```
String uppers = str1.replaceAll("[^A-Z]", "");
int length    = uppers.length();
```

Comment: I am using Java 7 and \\W is not recognized. I tried it with [^A-Z] which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
    String str1 = "";
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str1);
    int count = 0;

    System.out.println("ENTER A SENTENCE");
    str1 = sc.nextLine();

    while (matcher.find())
```

will not work like you think. You match on the empty string. It doesn't matter that you re-assing `str1` later.

Move the line

```
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str1);
```

just before the while loop, when your `str1` variable references the string you really want to match, e.g. the user's input.

In addition, you want to remove the `+` sign from your regex, as it macthes consecutive sequences of upper case letters at once.

Comment: @anuj Just increase the counter on each macth. Note that in the code you posted, the counter gets incremented only once after the macthings. (Use `while (...) { ... }`)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the old way of converting the string in char array using `toCharArray` method of String and then simply iterating the array. Check in each iteration if the char is in the range of 65 to 90 [ ASCII value of A is 65 and Z is 90]. Increment for each true case.