# Finding similar words in multiple string (Intersection)

Tags: java, string

For example,

```
String a = "cat dog monkey";
String b = "cat cow monkey";
String c = "cat dog duck";
```

I wonder whether is there any fast and efficient way to do it in Java, in order to find the intersected words of multiple strings, in this case will be "cat".

Comment: I'd say split the strings then do something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851938/efficiently-finding-the-intersection-of-a-variable-number-of-sets-of-strings?rq=1

Comment: I'd say at least do something.

Comment: You must first define "intersection". Does it include both "position of text" and "Text" ? or is it only the text which you want to check?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd split each string to an array, convert it to a `Set` and use the `retainAll` method:

```
String a = "cat dog monkey";
String b = "cat cow monkey";
String c = "cat dog duck";

Set<String> aSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(a.split(" ")));
Set<String> bSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(a.split(" ")));
Set<String> cSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(a.split(" ")));

Set<String> result = new HashSet<>(aSet);
result.retainAll(bSet);
result.retainAll(cSet);
```

Comment: Thank you, retainAll is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you know word exists at start of the string you can use method
   `a.startsWith("cat")`
2. If you know word exists at end of the string
   you can use method `a.endsWith("cat")`
3. If it is anywhere in the string `a.contains("cat")`, but that would be case sensitive.
4. You can use Regular Expressions also , to find it in any place.

To find intersection , here is a code example already given

[[Intersection of two strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448370/intersection-of-two-strings-in-java][1])