# How to check If a string contains a part of another string? (not the whole string)

Tags: java, string

I have 2 strings:

**1)** John has 2 apples.

**2)** Cody plays xbox in John's basement.

Now these 2 strings have "`John`" in common

But there seems to be no programmatic way to check this. The closest I could get is how to check if a string contains a specific word: `str1.toLowerCase().contains(str2.toLowerCase())`

So how do I check If String 1) contains part of String 2)?

Comment: you need to more specific, note that both strings contain an `" "` as well, or a `"o"` and `"p"`, etc.

Comment: @luk2302 I never thought about that and that Does make sense. Maybe this is the reason why this method doesn't exist

Comment: @luk2302 can I separate the words using special characters and then check IF those words are contained in string 1?

Comment: `str1.toLowerCase().contains(str2.toLowerCase()) && ! str1.equalsIgnoreCase(str2)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4448435/3790546

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no efficient way of doing this (without something that's O(n^2) complexity. As you could imagine, you'd probably have to make a matrix of the two (char by char) and do some checking for double letters in diagonals. EDIT never-mind, @Pablo says it can be done in O(m + n).

Comment: @Pablo Is that a duplicate? The other question is about common characters. This question is about common parts which is a different thing.

Comment: @user9598926 You have to be specific. Are you looking for the longest common substring?

Comment: @lexicore you are right, this questions is different

Comment: @1N5818 O(m+n) is probably for a different task. As for this I think tries can help a lot.

Comment: @user9598926, This is a nice question but you have to define what do you mean by "part".

Answer (score 1):

This could work

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = "John has 2 apples.";
    String y = "Cody plays xbox in John's basement.";
    // print words of x that matches any of y
    findMatch(Arrays.asList(x.split(" ")), y);
    // print words of y that matches any of x
    findMatch(Arrays.asList(y.split(" ")), x);

}

private static void findMatch(List<String> firstArr,String statement) {
    for (String string : firstArr) {
        if(statement.contains(string)) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that in the reverse order : search any word of `y` in `x` will not work as `"John's"` is not contained in `"John has 2 apples."`

Comment: the op clarified that he wants this " how do I check If String 1) contains part of String 2)? " @davidxxx

Comment: It is an example. A code should work in multiple "normal" cases otherwise it is hardcoded, which makes no sense. So why not just output "John" ?

Comment: can both strings be split into words and checked if string 2 contains words from string 1?

Comment: thank you @davidxxx for the explanation , I've edited my code for both cases , if there is another approach to do this could you add it to answers here ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about two strings, you would have to create a matrix of each with respect to eachother, i.e.

1) "`abcd`"

2) "`cdef`"

Matrix)

```
ac bc cc dc
ad bd cd dd
ae be ce de
af bc cf df
```

Then check for doubles to show up in diagnal patterns, (i.e., `cc` and `dd` ) in the above example.

This means, you will have to iterate through each string for each char of the other string, so I believe this would give you O(n^2) time complexity. For each diagonal match up, that would be a token that matches (and there could be more than one). This is not the same thing as longest common substring, as @lexicore said.

If they are really large strings, you probably wouldn't want to go through each char, but instead tokenize them (i.e. by splitting them by spaces) and creating a sorted list for each (or hash table or something) so you could itterate through each one in O(log n)ish time. I think that would give you something like O((log n)^2), but at least better than O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/4448435/3790546:

```
private static List<String> interection(String s1, String s2) {
    HashSet<String> h1, h2;
    h1 = toHashSet(s1);
    h2 = toHashSet(s2);
    h1.retainAll(h2);
    return h1.stream().collect(toList());
}

private static HashSet<String> toHashSet(String s) {
    return Arrays.stream(s.split("[\\s@&.'?$+-]+")).collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
}

public static void main (String [] args) {
    interection("John has 2 apples.", "Cody plays xbox in John's basement.").forEach(System.out::println);
}
```