# Find the item with the most matched property

Tags: javascript, regex, algorithm

**Condition.**

There are uppercase alaphabet items

```
items = [ "FUCAMVLNDI", "KXRMGDPOHU", "GPMKEUFLQJ", 
"YHBURQPOFM", "VKURNBXTIH", "IGLOTVNPEY", "SLCGRJOPYB",
"HUDGIFNTPM", "EPHLCQZFOR", "TYDIAVUQZW", "KTYBZPXSHG",
"CWXMLTFDJI", "ERCJSWPFYH", "TQSHIKRCMJ", "JHBOYCFWAK",
"NPVAMTLXBQ", "BIWAUNPSOT", "TQZARXMSLH", "JLYDFHWMTN",
"XODHNVFCWM", "EWZFKXRIVM", "KVEWZRXIMA"
```

1. There are given string which is 10 length, uppercase alphabet, like `BIWAUNPSOT` each called `item` above
2. Each Alphabet in `item` is a meta data ( or property ),  not just a alphabet.
3. So i want to find a `item` in `items` using `regex` which presents condition of the most matching a given meta data of each `item`

   - Intersection of two string
   - If `YHBURQPOFM` matches `IGLOTVNPEY`. `Y, O, P` Three conditions are satisfied
4. In order to know the `most` satisfied condition, I thought i need to use `{ }` operator because it's countable so that i can find the most matching for each `item` with some logic. but it's hard to make regex to me. something wrong.
5. I would find `item` of  `items` using `match` method like

   - `items.toString().match(item_regex);`
   - My problem is `item_regex`
   - But is there another good way to find the `most` matching item? not using `regex`?

---

**What i did**

```
for ( let i = 0; i < items.length; i ++){
  // make RegExp using each item
  const regex = new RegExp('\\b[' + items[i] + ']{' + increase + '}\\w+', 'g');
  const matchedList = items.toString().match(regex)
  if ( matchedList === null ) {
     // the previous one was the most matched condition
     // So I thought that ( increase - 1 ) is the most matched condition 
  } else {
     increase++;
     i=0;
  }
}
```

The example of regex what i thought is

`\b[item]{increase}\w+`

It might be something like

`\b[YHBURQPOFM]{7}\w+`

But never mind. I think this is totally wrong

**So My Question is**

1. What is the best `regex` which meet the condition i mentioned

   - I need `2~n items` with the most matching ,
   - I need the number for the most matching ( How many match each item, it can be 1~10 because, the given string is 10 length )
   - with the code above, I can get `2~n items` through `matchedList`

     I can get number for the most matching through `increase`, `{ } operator`
   - I'm trying to match each alphabet in any other. ex) `ABCDEFGHIJ` and `AXBCDEFGHI` is the match = 9  but also `JIHGFEDCBA` and `AXBCDEFGHI` is the match = 9
2. Was it wrong approach? i mean, Using regex is a bad idea for this solution?

### Edit

**The most matching means**

Intersection with two string.
For example

If `YHBURQPOFM` matches `IGLOTVNPEY`. `Y, O, P`, Three conditions are satisfied

So I would search every `item` for the whole `items`
so that i can find the most matching

they can be 3 couples with satisfying 7 conditions, they can be 2 couples with satisfying 8 conditions

If 0 couples with satisfying 9 conditions, then 8 is the most matching

Comment: I still do not understand your definition of "most matching".  Please explain with examples.

Comment: are you trying to match each alphabet in the order, ex: ABCDEFGHIJ and AXBCDEFGHI is the match = 9 or 1?

Comment: @PM77-1 I edited my question. Sorry for bad English. But i think you can understand it

Comment: @GlenK that is the match = 9 but, JIHGFEDCBA and AXBCDEFGHI is also the match = 9

Comment: You need intersection between two strings?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448370/intersection-of-two-strings-in-java

Comment: @PM77-1 Right, I appreciate your answer. but not enough for my problem. for short. I need ```regex``` which need the match count and match alphabet specified in any order

Comment: Your task is ill suited for RegEx and under normal business circumstances should be solved by other means.

Comment: If your [other question with the same topic/problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59084480/a-question-about-this-regexp-balpahbetnumber-w) is no longer of interest than delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 functions:

1. A function that takes 2 strings and returns the number of intersections between them (if the strings are identical return is `null`)
2. A function that takes an array of strings and on each string returns an array of sub arrays ([string A, string B, number of intersections between both strings])

Details commented in demo

```js
const data = ["FUCAMVLNDI", "KXRMGDPOHU", "GPMKEUFLQJ",
  "YHBURQPOFM", "VKURNBXTIH", "IGLOTVNPEY", "SLCGRJOPYB",
  "HUDGIFNTPM", "EPHLCQZFOR", "TYDIAVUQZW", "KTYBZPXSHG",
  "CWXMLTFDJI", "ERCJSWPFYH", "TQSHIKRCMJ", "JHBOYCFWAK",
  "NPVAMTLXBQ", "BIWAUNPSOT", "TQZARXMSLH", "JLYDFHWMTN",
  "XODHNVFCWM", "EWZFKXRIVM", "KVEWZRXIMA"
];

/* 
 ** Pass 2 strings returns the total number of intersections
 */
const intCount = (stringA, stringB) => {
  // If strings are identical return null
  if (stringA === stringB) {
    return null;
  }
  // Convert both strings into an array of letters
  const A = stringA.split('');
  const B = stringB.split('');
  /* Array C is an array of letters for each time there's a matched letter
  between array A and array B */
  let C = A.filter(letter => B.includes(letter));
  // Return the total number of intersections
  return C.length;
}

/*
 ** Pass an array of strings returns an array:
 ** [ stringA, stringB, greatest number of intersections]
 */
const intSets = array => {
  // flatMap creates a 2 dimensional map and flattens it
  let map = array.flatMap((word, index, group) => {
    // Declare a word by index as a fixed reference
    const fixed = group[index];
    // Declare an empty array
    let set = [];
    // Iterate thru the array of words...
    for (let word of group) {
      // Declare an empty array...
      let pairs = [];
      // Add the fixed word to pairs array
      pairs.push(fixed);
      // Add the current word to pairs array
      pairs.push(word);
      // Add the return value of intCount() of both words
      pairs.push(intCount(fixed, word));
      // Add the pairs array to the set array
      set.push(pairs);
    }
    // Return set array of [string A, string B, intersection count] 
    return set;
    // console.log(set);
  });
  // Return the array in descending order of each pairs array number (index [2]).
  let ordered = map.sort((setA, setB) => setB[2] - setA[2]);
  // Return the pairs array with the greatest number of intersections
  return ordered[0];
}

console.log(intSets(data));
```