# How do I find intersections of consecutive characters in strings?

Tags: c#, string

Suppose I had the following strings:

1. `blahFOOblahblah`
2. `blahblahBARblah`
3. `FIZZblahblahblah`

Now, I want to interrogate each of these to discover which of them contain any substring of the following:

`FIZZbuzz`

Obviously, this string shares the word "FIZZ" in common with #3.

I have already taken a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090453/implementing-an-efficent-algorithm-to-find-the-intersection-of-two-strings), which doesn't quite accomplish what I am after since it simply focuses on characters (in any order) rather than substrings.

Comment: Hint: It's a triply nested loop, comparing every character in your candidate string with every character in each of the target strings.

Comment: It also has `F` in common with #1, and `b` in common with all three. Exactly what is the criteria?

Comment: Actually it has "FIZZb" in common, no?

Comment: @Matthew: How many characters constitutes a match?

Comment: And what exactly would you expect the result to be for `FIZblahFIZZblah` (`FIZ` is one intersection, `FIZZb` is another)

Comment: 1 character is a substring, but it sounds like you don't want to match single characters. You'll have to specify the minimum and maximum number of characters you want to match.

Comment: @IgbyLargeman--I would most likely be interested in 3+ characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for something like [longest common substring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem)?

There are fast, but quite complicated algorithms which solve the task by building and using [suffix trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree). They have `O(n)` time for constant size alphabet, and `O(n log(n))` time in the worst case, where `n` is the maximal length of strings.

Below is a possible C# implementation (from http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring). It is not optimal, but could be sufficient in our case.

```
public int LongestCommonSubstring(string str1, string str2, out string sequence)
{
    sequence = string.Empty;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str1) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(str2))
        return 0;

    int[,] num = new int[str1.Length, str2.Length];
    int maxlen = 0;
    int lastSubsBegin = 0;
    StringBuilder sequenceBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < str1.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < str2.Length; j++)
        {
            if (str1[i] != str2[j])
                num[i, j] = 0;
            else
            {
                if ((i == 0) || (j == 0))
                    num[i, j] = 1;
                else
                    num[i, j] = 1 + num[i - 1, j - 1];

                if (num[i, j] > maxlen)
                {
                    maxlen = num[i, j];
                    int thisSubsBegin = i - num[i, j] + 1;
                    if (lastSubsBegin == thisSubsBegin)
                    {//if the current LCS is the same as the last time this block ran
                        sequenceBuilder.Append(str1[i]);
                    }
                    else //this block resets the string builder if a different LCS is found
                    {
                        lastSubsBegin = thisSubsBegin;
                        sequenceBuilder.Length = 0; //clear it
                        sequenceBuilder.Append(str1.Substring(lastSubsBegin, (i + 1) - lastSubsBegin));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    sequence = sequenceBuilder.ToString();
    return maxlen;
}
```

Comment: What does that funny little `U` mean?

Comment: Doesn't even look like valid Pascal.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's just copy and pasted pseudo-code

Comment: This looks promising. . .

Comment: @cost, I agree, Not sure this constitutes an answer to a c# question.

Comment: There is a C# section in the Wikipedia article.  Checking it now. . .

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring#C.23

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt Yep. I also found this page and than read your comment. Thank you anyway!

Comment: This works well.  I had to set a threshold to 4 characters or greater to get meaningful results.  Thanks.