# Winforms dot.net Detect if more than x alphabets of string one are present in string two & vice versa

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string-comparison

I am working with a C# Windows form application. Can anyone help me with the fastest way to detect if more than 'x' number of  alphabets of string one are present in string two in same pattern & vice versa.

Example: "dog" in "puppydogphotos.jpg" would count as a detection.

I am doing something like below but its failing on some instances:

```
foreach (var word in Kewords.Split(','))
{
    var filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e.FullPath).ToLower();
    var extenion = Path.GetExtension(e.FullPath).ToLower();

    if (word.ToLower().Contains(filename) || word.ToLower().StartsWith(filename) || word.ToLower().EndsWith(filename) || word.Contains(extenion) || filename.ToLower().Contains(word.ToLower()) ||filename.ToLower().StartsWith(word) || filename.ToLower().EndsWith(word))
    {  
      keywordMatch = true;
    }
}
```

***Thanks***

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you are trying to detect? Surely it should be filename.contains(word) rather than word.contains(filename)

Comment: Let's improve the things... This `if` statement looks very long and horrible! You don't need to check for `StartsWith` or `EndsWith` if you use `Contains` and ||. Also, just convert using `ToLower` once and then call `Contains`, because it will have the same effect as the whole statement.
So all you need is the first condition in your if.

Comment: Ok, Case 1: suppose string 1 has "verybaddata.jpg" & string 2 has "bad" or "dda", I want to return a true. Case 2:  suppose string 1 has "trex.txt" & string 2 has "ex.tx" or "rex", I want to return a true. (true means that more than 2 characters in sequence are shared by two string variables).

Comment: @Robin all you need in this case is `ToLower` and `Contains`. You don't need to check anything else. Furthermore you don't need `if` statement. All you need to return is `word.ToLower().Contains(filename)` which will tell you whether it's true or false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like method

```
    String.Intersect
```

should be able to help you.

Small example here: [Implementing an efficent algorithm to find the intersection of two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090453/implementing-an-efficent-algorithm-to-find-the-intersection-of-two-strings)

Comment: If all you have to offer is a link to another QA, it should be a comment

Comment: Ok, got it - moving it there

Comment: Turns out I don't have enough reputation to comment - what is best way to add my answer in this case, could you please help me?

Comment: Thanks @Alex & Imaver wish I can mark both as answer. Thanks both of you a lot.